# Is there a way to set the size of a snackbar when calling it in the Enqueue function (material desinge)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

```
/* -- Calling snackbar -- */
public static Snackbar getSnackbar()
{
   Snackbar snackbar = new Snackbar()
   {
      Height = 350,
      Width = 400,
      MessageQueue = new SnackbarMessageQueue(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000)),
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom
   };

   return snackbar;
}

SnackbarMessage message = new SnackbarMessage()
   {
      Height = 350,
      Width = 400,
   };
Snackbar snackbar = getSnackbar();
snackbar.message = message;
```

Now when I activate the `snackbar` like that

```
snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(messageGrid);
```

it doesn't take the defined width and height.

When I activate it like that:

```
snackbar.IsActive = true;
```

it takes the defined width and height

Does someone know how I can define the dimensions when I call the `.Enqueue` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dimensions of the Snackbar just before calling `Enqueue` (Tested)

```
var messageString = "my message";
snackbar.MinWidth = 100;
snackbar.MaxWidth = 1000;
snackbar.Width = 200;
snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(messageString);
```

or setting `IsActive` to true (Tested)

```
snackbar.message = snackbarMessageObject;
snackbar.Width = 300;
snackbar.IsActive = true;
```

I suggest you not to use `SnackbarMessage`, because you should take into account many constraints like the Margin/Padding/Width/Height/MinWidth/MinHeight of both `Snackbar` and `SnackbarMessage`, so sometimes you won't get the proper look!

Comment: Yes this works with the width but not with the height, i want to Enqueue with a Grid to fit more information into the snackbar and therefore i want to change the height.